# How do I make an AngularJS directive manipulate all elements associated with it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, dom-manipulation, window-resize

I have a directive that modifies the width of it's associated 'element'. It works great upon first page load, but I want it to change the width based on the size of the window. I added a 'window.onresize' function but it will only affect the LAST ELEMENT associated with the directive. Why isn't it affecting all of them?

Here is my directive code, and here is a plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/ytXSY1gtxQRAVLEHxRMY?p=preview

```
angular.module('app', ['components'])
angular.module('components', [])

.directive('gallerySlide', function() {    
  function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    function resize() {
      element[0].style.width = window.innerWidth - 300 + 'px';
    }
    resize();
    window.onresize = resize;
    }
  return {
    link: link
  };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@gtramontina is correct about `onresize` being reassigned everytime the link function is run. Here I suggest another solution using jQuery to manage events queue and **remember to avoid memory leaks** by handling scope's `$destroy` event:

```
.directive('gallerySlide', function() {

  return {
    link:  function link(scope, element, attrs) {

    var id = Math.random(); //generate random id so that we can un-register event handler to avoid memory leaks.

    function resize()
    {
      element[0].style.width = window.innerWidth - 300 + 'px';
    }
    resize();
    $(window).on("resize",id,resize);

      scope.$on("$destroy",function(){ //this is important to avoid memory leaks.
          $(window).off("resize",id);
     });
     }
   };
});
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/ys1P6fi90qK3YOtJxGuX?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're re-assigning the `onresize` listener every time the directive runs its link function.

Here: http://plnkr.co/edit/CCHgndK4cxCBMUfzTeil?p=preview

**Edit:**

```
.directive('gallerySlide', function() {

  var elements = [];

  function resize () {
    elements.forEach(function (element) {
      element.style.width = window.innerWidth - 300 + 'px';
    });
  };

  window.onresize = resize;

  function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    elements.push(element[0]);
    resize();
    }

  return {
    link: link
  };
});
```

By the way, try other ways of binding to `window.onresize`. Maybe injecting `$window` and than doing something `$window.on('resize', resize)` – don't recall if such thing works/exists, though.